# Inheritance in custom attributes

Tags: android, attributes

I have an attribute eg "parent" in my attrs file

```
 <declare-styleable name="parent">
    <attr name="text" format="string" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

Now I want another attribute set which contains the attributes in "parent" and also has other attributes

```
 <declare-styleable name="child">
    <attr name="text2" format="string" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

Can you please let me know how to inherit parent into child

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<declare-styleable name="child" parent="@declare-styleable/parent">
    <attr name="text2" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```